# Decode 2D Polygon coordinates using Struct's Encodable protocol

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, codable

I am trying to parse the below json using Encodable protocol of Swift Struct.
If I make the coordinates `Any` or of `AnyObject` it give error saying not conforming to the protocol.

I know this can be achieved using Arrays & Dictionary but I don't want to do it in that way.

```
{
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [
                0.148271,
                51.6723432
            ],
            [
                0.148271,
                51.3849401
            ],
            [
                -0.3514683,
                51.3849401
            ],
            [
                -0.3514683,
                51.6723432
            ],
            [
                0.148271,
                51.6723432
            ]
        ]
    ]
} 

struct Geometry: Codable {
    let coordinates: [[[Double]]]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let data = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        coordinates = try data.decode([[[Double]]].self, forKey: .coordinates)
    }
}

do {
    let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Geometry.self, from: data!)
    print(decoded)
    completionHandler(statusCode, decoded)
} catch {
    print("Failed to encode data.")
    completionHandler(statusCode, nil)
}
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to make `CLLocationCoordinate2D` conform to `Codable` decoding an array of `Double`

```
import CoreLocation

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D : Codable {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var arrayContainer = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        if arrayContainer.count == 2 {
            let lat = try arrayContainer.decode(CLLocationDegrees.self)
            let lng = try arrayContainer.decode(CLLocationDegrees.self)
            self.init(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
        } else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: arrayContainer, debugDescription: "Coordinate array must contain two items")
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var arrayContainer = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
        try arrayContainer.encode(contentsOf: [latitude, longitude])
    }
}
```

Then you can declare `Geometry` simply

```
struct Geometry: Codable {
    let coordinates: [[CLLocationCoordinate2D]]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The data snippet you presented in your original question (before you edited it several times after reading my comments) was not valid JSON.
If you put curly brackets around everything (which you now have), it would be a valid JSON object with a 'coordinates' field. But from your (original) question I understand that that's probably not what you want. The next best thing you can get that is valid JSON would be the Array (i.e. the content of the 'coordinates' field.)

The following code snippet gives the JSON object:

```
import Foundation

let sample  = [[[0.148271, 51.6723432], [0.148272, 51.6723433], [0.148273, 51.6723434],]]

struct Geometry: Codable {
    var coordinates: [[[Double]]]

    init(coord: [[[Double]]]) {
        self.coordinates = coord
    }

////  Remove the comments below in order use a simple JSON array!
//    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
//        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
//        try container.encode(coordinates)
//    }
//
//    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
//        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
//        coordinates = try container.decode([[[Double]]].self)
//    }
}

// Initialize a Geometry object
let geo = Geometry(coord: sample)

// Serialize into `data` and print the result
let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(geo)
print (String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "-not representable-")

// Now, decode the data into a new Geometry instance `g` and print it
let g = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Geometry.self, from: data)
print (g)
```

This results in (JSON formatted for better readability):

```
{
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [
        0.14827099999999999,
        51.6723432
      ],
      [
        0.14827199999999999,
        51.672343300000001
      ],
      [
        0.14827299999999999,
        51.672343400000003
      ]
    ]
  ]
}

Geometry(coordinates: [[[0.148271, 51.6723432], [0.148272, 51.6723433], [0.148273, 51.6723434]]])
```

If you remove the comments in the example code, you get the array without the curly brackets, but also without the "coordinates": label (JSON formatted for better readability):

```
[
  [
    [
      0.14827099999999999,
      51.6723432
    ],
    [
      0.14827199999999999,
      51.672343300000001
    ],
    [
      0.14827299999999999,
      51.672343400000003
    ]
  ]
]

Geometry(coordinates: [[[0.148271, 51.6723432], [0.148272, 51.6723433], [0.148273, 51.6723434]]])
```

Comment: Lutz, it is a valid JSON. Root object of JSON can be Array. Read here for more info: http://json.org/

Comment: subdan, that's what I said. But inspect the data snippet in the question: it starts with "coordinates":[[[.... and that's NOT valid JSON. My answer takes the array case into account.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. I didn't notice.

Comment: @Lutz you are reading the coordinates from just a simple array and not from key value.

Comment: @Anirudha you are right. In my example the data are initialized from a simple array for simplicity. But then they are encoded into json data, printed, and then decoded from the same data again. So the example covers the complete roundtrip of encoding and decoding. Try it out: copy my code and paste it into a Swift Playground.

Comment: @Lutz thanks for you help but your code will work fine on the example you gave, it doesn't seems to work on for my example, it goes to the catch block again.

Comment: @Lutz your JSON doesn't have a key which I can infer for data. If you just look at my JSON, it has a key which is `coordinate` and value associated with it.

Comment: @Anirudha I see. But with a key "coordinates": (before your edit) or "result": (after your last edit) this is not valid JSON. If you need a key, you need to use curly braces around the whole stuff. If it's not valid JSON, you won't be able to parse it with the JSONDecoder. Refer to [json.org](http://json.org) for information about valid json or try [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com) to check your data for well-fomedness.